# Which Geologic time scale is the most accurate?

Tags: zoology, biogeography, scales

I kindly ask to show me some pictures that is a generally accurate geologic time scale.

In google, a lot of geo time scales are different.

On what i have searched there are 2 major eons which are

I.Precambrian eon
 1. Archean eon
 2. Hadean eon 
 3. Proterozoic eon

II.Phanerozoic eon

1. Palezoic
2. Mesozoic

3.Cenozoic

But along with it Precrambiann is further divided to proterozoic eon, archaaen eon and hadeon eon are **ERAS** of but it clearly says its an **EON**.

And how about in Phanerozoic eon?

Kindly please clarify the following. Thank you!!

Comment: I don;t quite understand your question. The only question mark in your post is "And how about in Phanerozoic eon?" which question is rather vague. Are you asking for the subdivision of the Phanerozoic eon? It would not match with the title. Are you asking "What is the difference between an eon and an era?"?

Comment: According to these Wikipedia pages - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geologic_time_scale#Table_of_geologic_time, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precambrian - the Precambrian is a "supereon" not an "eon".

Answer (score 1):

According to these Wikipedia pages - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geologic_time_scale#Table_of_geologic_time, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precambrian - the Precambrian is a "supereon" not an "eon".

The [ICS International Chronostratigraphic Chart](http://www.stratigraphy.org/index.php/ics-chart-timescale), ambiguously, puts "Eonothem/Eon" over both the "Precambrian" column and the "Hadean - Archean - Proterozoic" column, with the next column over being "Erathem/Era", which corresponds to what's in the other periods.

It seems clear that 1) the Hadean, Archean and Proterozoic are considered "Eons" like the Phanerozoic is (with their sub-divisions all being called "Eras"), 2) the Precambrian is a larger period of time that encompasses the Hadea, Archean and Proterozoic, and 3) there might be some disagreement as to how to name the period of time the Precambrian is; Wikipedia says "Supereon", which makes sense, but the ICS chart doesn't include that word and seems happy to have it share the name "Eon" with its immediate subdivisions. But the name is just a name, the more important things are how the different periods relate to each other, which is covered by 1) and 2).